# Forming a new hash structure by merging two hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, data-structures, hash

I have two hashes of the same format. My target is to create a new hash by taking values from the two hashes, changing the keys inside first. I have explained in My Goal down below what I would like to have as an output. I couldnot go forward from here, please help.

**What I have**

```
h1 = {
 "x"=> {
  "imp"=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2},
  "ctr"=> {"a"=>3, "b"=>4}
  },
 "y"=> {
  "imp"=> {"c"=>1, "d"=>2},
  "ctr"=> {"c"=>3, "d"=>4}
  },
 "z"=> {
  "imp"=> {"e"=>10, "f"=>20, "g"=> 111},
  "ctr"=> {"e"=>30, "f"=>40, "g"=> 222}
   } 
} 

h2 = {
 "x"=> {
  "imp"=>{"a"=>11, "b"=>22},
  "ctr"=>{"a"=>33, "b"=>44}
 },
 "y"=> {
  "imp"=> {"c"=>11, "d"=>22},
  "ctr"=>{"c"=>33, "d"=>44}
 },
 "z"=> {
  "imp"=>{"e"=>11, "f"=>22, "g"=> 333},
  "ctr"=>{"e"=>55, "f"=>66, "g"=> 444}
 }
}
```

**MY GOAL**

```
{segment=>"x=a", "imp"=>1, "ctr"=>3, "imp_of_h2"=>11, "ctr_of_h2"=>33}, 
{segment=>"x=b", "imp"=>2, "ctr"=>4, "imp_of_h2"=>22, "ctr_of_h2"=>44},
{segment=>"y=c", "imp"=>1, "ctr"=>3, "imp_of_h2"=>11, "ctr_of_h2"=>33},
{segment=>"y=d", "imp"=>2, "ctr"=>4, "imp_of_h2"=>22, "ctr_of_h2"=>44},
{segment=>"z=e", "imp"=>10, "ctr"=>4, "imp_of_h2"=>22, "ctr_of_h2"=>55},
{segment=>"z=f", "imp"=>20, "ctr"=>40, "imp_of_h2"=>22, "ctr_of_h2"=>66},
{segment=>"z=g", "imp"=>111, "ctr"=>222, "imp_of_h2"=>333, "ctr_of_h2"=>444}
```

**What I tried so far..** But it is only functional for one hash only. I needed to achieve this for the two hashes.

```
data_final = []
h1.flat_map do |segment, attrs|
  segments = attrs.values.flat_map(&:keys).uniq
  # create a segment entry for each unique letter
  segments.map do |seg|
    row = {"segment" => "#{segment}=#{seg}"}
    row.merge! Hash[attrs.keys.map {|key| [key,attrs[key][seg]]}]
    data_final << row
  end      
end
```

Comment: These aren't even valid hashes...

Comment: So, what are the specific rules for this transformation? Write them down.

Comment: The rule is to create one entry 'segment' whose value is the first key 'x' in the example add '=' then pick the letter from the inside say 'a' and then state its corresponding associations like imps => value, ctr => value etc. From the output, it's more clear

Comment: Yep, so what's the problem with implementing this logic?

Comment: Can you @SergioTulentsev see how I tried from the question, I could do it for one of the hashes, but am stuck trying to achieve adding the  attributes of the second hash, could you help?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have edited the hashes to be valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58940/discussion-between-kb-enreach-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Answer (score 0):

Pragmatically speaking, is this what you wanted? (Don't forget to install `y_support` gem for `Array#>>` method.)

```
require 'y_support/core_ext' # gem install y_support if necessary

labels = "imp", "ctr"
h2_suffix = "_of_h2"

result = [ [?x, ?a], [?x, ?b], [?y, ?c], [?y, ?d], [?z, ?e], [?z, ?f], [?z, ?g] ].map do
  |coordinate, letter|
  [ "segment", *labels, *labels.map { |lbl| lbl + h2_suffix } ] >>
    [ "#{coordinate}=#{letter}",
      *labels.map { |label| h1[coordinate][label][letter] },
      *labels.map { |label| h2[coordinate][label][letter] } ]
end
```